# Variable in a class instance is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, accord.net

I am using a demo sample from a class library named Accord.net All the referenses are ok but I get the following error message:

> 1>  All packages listed in D:\Software Projects\Classification (SVMs)\packages.config are already installed.
>
> 1>D:\Software Projects\Classification (SVMs)\MainForm.cs(174,42,174,50): error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'GetRange' and no extension method 'GetRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 1>D:\Software Projects\Classification (SVMs)\MainForm.cs(177,37,177,46): error CS0117: 'Accord.Math.Matrix' does not contain a definition for 'Cartesian'
>
> 1>D:\Software Projects\Classification (SVMs)\MainForm.cs(178,17,178,23): error CS0122: 'Accord.Math.Vector' is inaccessible due to its protection level
>
> 1>D:\Software Projects\Classification (SVMs)\MainForm.cs(179,17,179,23): error CS0122: 'Accord.Math.Vector' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I can not modify the protection level of those classes to e.g public as I do not have access to them.  What can I do to let this compile?

Comment: If the properties are inaccessible (private, protected, internal) then you don't access them.  Why are you trying to?  If you can't modify the library then the vendor of the library clearly doesn't intend for it to be used the way you're trying to.

Comment: Can we have a link to this demo sample ?

Comment: The sample is here: http://accord-framework.net/samples.html#  it is labeled Handwriting multiclass SVM  - I am not modifying any of the code that is provided - I just mentioned it as a possiblity to be able to let it compile.

Comment: By commenting out the following code the solution compiles;
           // Get the ranges for each variable (X and Y)
            DoubleRange[] ranges = table.GetRange(0);

            // Generate a Cartesian coordinate system
            double[][] map = Matrix.Cartesian(
                Vector.Interval(ranges[0], 0.05),
                Vector.Interval(ranges[1], 0.05));

            // Classify each point in the Cartesian coordinate system
            double[] result = ....

            CreateScatterplot(zedGraphControl2, surface);